How to use Sqlalchemy python query result as an object like in NodeJS?
i want to ask how we use the result of a sqlalchemy orm query for function that located in another file like i used it in NodeJS. I never use python before so it would be great if anybody can help me with this.
database.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text, select, Table, String, ForeignKey, Text, BLOB
import sqlalchemy as sa

DB_URL = "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/dem-db"
engine = create_engine(DB_URL, echo=True, client_encoding="utf8")

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class TipeSurat(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TipeSurat"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    code: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    filePath: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    fileTemplate: Mapped[bytearray] = mapped_column(BLOB)
    createdAt: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    updatedAt: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text)
    
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
         return f"TipeSurat(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r}, code={self.code!r}, filePath={self.filePath!r}, createdAt={self.createdAt!r}, updatedAt={self.updatedAt!r})"
    
def getData(name):
    session = Session(engine)
    stmt = select(TipeSurat).where(TipeSurat.name.match('Nota Dinas'))
    dataTable = session.scalars(stmt)
    return dataTable


the picture above show the fields in data table in case im doing it wrong in my data model at database.py
main.py
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
from docx import Document
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
import database

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

def fill_invitation(template_path, output_path, data):
    doc = Document(template_path)
    data['tgl'] = datetime.today().strftime("%d %B %Y")
    
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key in paragraph.text:
                # paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(key, value)
                for index, run in enumerate(paragraph.runs):
                    if paragraph.runs[index-1].text == '[' and paragraph.runs[index+1].text == ']' and run.text == key:
                        run.text = run.text.replace(key, value)
                        paragraph.runs[index-1].text = ''
                        paragraph.runs[index+1].text = ''
    doc.save(output_path)

@app.route('/getTemplate', methods=['POST'])

def docsFilling():
    data = request.get_json()
    templateData = data.get('template')
    # pprint(vars(data))
    # -- this is the the part that did not works --
    listTipeSurat = database.getData(templateData)
    for e in listTipeSurat:
        if templateData == e.name
        template = e.templfileTemplate
    # ---------------------------------------------
    output = 'filled ' + datetime.now().strftime("%d %B %Y") + '.docx'
    fill_invitation(template, output, data)
    # filename = os.path.join(app.config['FACTURAS_FOLDER'], output)
    return send_file(output, download_name='docs.pdf', mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

i have database that connect to existing DB using postgresql and i have confirm that the query works but after all of these, how we use the result into the conditional data and use the blob file to create the template in fill_invitation function
Thanks before!

Read the docs Flask Quickstart and Flask-SQLAlchemy for starters.
